# Post form, product id and date to database

Tags: magento2

I have created module to post comments. Basically I have added a new tab called Comments to product page view (just like reviews tab). So far I have managed to output comments based on product ID. Now I am creating post controller, it should save the form (name, email, text) and also add to database current product Id and date(created at). How can I achieve this?

This is my post controller:

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\ProductComments\Controller\Post;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;



class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $item = $this->_objectManager->create("Vendor\ProductComments\Model\Comments");
        $item->setData($data);
        $item->save();
        $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $redirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $redirect;
    }
}
```

And this is my form.phtml:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("comments/post/index")?>" method="post">


<div class="field comment-field-name required">
    <label for="name_field" class="label"><span>Name</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name_field">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field comment-field-email required">
    <label for="email_field" class="label"><span>Email</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email_field">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field comment-field-text required">
    <label for="comment_field" class="label"><span>Comment</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment_field" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="primary actions-primary">
    <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span>Submit</span></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by current product and created time? At what page are you implementing this?

Comment: I have added 1 more tab Comments to product page (like review, details). Inside that tab, is comment list and form for new comments. Very similar to reviews tab.

Comment: Please add this to your question so that it helps others understand.

Comment: Ok, I edited it!

Comment: Do you have column in your table in database to store product_id and date created if not you have to create those.

Comment: And another think do you mean comment created time by date created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have created column to store time and productid in your database and appropriate model for it. Apart from that you may proceed like this.

**1. Create Block file**

Since you have not shown your block file I assume that it is common file extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. Inject with it **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description** class.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class YourBlockFile extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        ...
        Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description $description,
        ...
) 
    {
        ...
        $this->description = $description;
        ...
    }
    public function getProductId()
    {   //This gets us the current product from the registry.
        return $this->description->getProduct()->getData('entity_id');
    }
}
```

**2. Create your form with two more hidden element.**

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("comments/post/index")?>" method="post">


<div class="field comment-field-name required">
    <label for="name_field" class="label"><span>Name</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input" name="name" id="name_field">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field comment-field-email required">
    <label for="email_field" class="label"><span>Email</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="email" class="input" name="email" id="email_field">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field comment-field-text required">
    <label for="comment_field" class="label"><span>Comment</span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment_field" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
        <input type="hidden" class="input" name="productid" id="productid" value="<?php echo $block->getProductId();?>" >
        <input type="hidden" class="input" name="timestamp" id="timestamp">
<div class="primary actions-primary">
    <button type="submit" class="action submit primary"><span>Submit</span></button>
</div>
</form>
```

**3. Controller: Just change the value of time stamp here.**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductComments\Controller\Post;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;



class Index extends Action
{
    protected $date;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date, // you must inject with this class to get correct store time.
        ....
    ) {
        ....
        $this->date = $date;
        ....
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $timestamp= $this->date->gmtDate();
        $this->getRequest()->setPostValue('timestamp', $timestamp); //since this field is empty initially set timestamp.
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $item = $this->_objectManager->create("Vendor\ProductComments\Model\Comments");
        $item->setData($data);
        $item->save();
        $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $redirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $redirect;
    }
}
```

This is how I have done to some similar problem of mine. Hope works for you.

Comment: You are always welcomed.